# ASP.NET Postback Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm learning ASP.NET and I don't understand what is going on here.

The code behind file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "TextBox1.Text = " + TextBox1.Text + "<br />";
    Label1.Text += "TextBox1.Forecolor = " TextBox1.ForeColor.ToString();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Some more text";
    TextBox1.ForColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
}
```

Essentially all there is just a label that tells you what the color and text of the textbox is. When you hit the button it changes the color to blue, and the page reloads.

Why is it that when you press the button the first time and the page reloads, the label does not update to the correct information? You have to press the button again for it to read that the text box is red.

Can anyone provide an explanation for this behavior? And how to change the Page_Load method to fix this issue?

Comment: take a look at [AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874.aspx)

Comment: Same exact thought that came to my mind, but I want to understand what is going on here before i just move on.

Comment: All page load code needs to be wrapped inside a if(!Page.IsPostback) block otherwise it would get executed on every postback.

Comment: Right, but that is good in this situation, because we are changing these labels based on the code that is inside the textbox. The problem is, like @tvanfosson mentioned, the order they load is not allowing for the label to read that the text has changed to blue when the button was pressed the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Page_Load event is being handled before the control events. See the description of the page lifecycle at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx.  To fix it, modify the code so that both Page_Load and the Button_Click handlers call the same method to set the label value. Only have Page_Load execute if the method isn't a POSTBACK.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       SetUpLabel();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Some more text";
    TextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

    SetUpLabel();
}

private void SetUpLabel()
{
    Label1.Text = "TextBox1.Text = " + TextBox1.Text + "<br />";
    Label1.Text += "TextBox1.Forecolor = " TextBox1.ForeColor.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why you call the  `SetUpLabel();` in button click event?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Because he wants the values to change based on the update to the text box in the button click handler.

Comment: So why you check the condition `if (!IsPostBack)` in page load? if the OP want that, then why you check? The current OP codes working good, if he want update

Comment: @RameshRajendran so that it doesn't run twice. The textbox isn't changed until the click handler runs later in the page lifecycle; there's no point in updating the label in page load because it's still the same values from the previous request at that point.

Comment: This works. It changes the label on the first click of the button. Is it possible to make this happen WITHOUT actually adding code to the Button1_Click method?

Comment: I guess I am just a little confused why this works. Is it correct to say that the SetUpLabel method is called BEFORE the postback, and the textbox's changes are just preserved?

Comment: @CadeWard - you could add a PreRender handler and set the label's value in it. Since that runs after both Page_Load and the control events that would be the only place it would need to be done. It isn't correct to say that it happens before POSTBACK - the click handler is only ever fired on POSTBACK, it's just that it's being updated after the textbox has been updated instead of before.

Answer (score 2):

You Need To Write The Code In Page_Load As Under:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack) //This condition allows a code to execute once when your page is load first time.
   {
    Label1.Text = "TextBox1.Text = " + TextBox1.Text + "<br />";
    Label1.Text += "TextBox1.Forecolor = " TextBox1.ForeColor.ToString();
   }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Some more text";
    TextBox1.ForColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

    Label1.Text = "TextBox1.Text = " + TextBox1.Text + "<br />";
    Label1.Text += "TextBox1.Forecolor = " TextBox1.ForeColor.ToString();

}
```

Comment: He wants the label to change to reflect the change to the textbox. This will force him to have to reload the page to get an updated label, which is what is unexpected and he thinks should not happen.

Comment: This makes sense, and this was also my first instinct. But now the labels are never updated after pressing the button. The labels need to always update to what is going on inside the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

try it, Simply try this code, this codes alway's work, don't need extra code

```
bool IsClick=false;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Label1.Text = "TextBox1.Text = " + TextBox1.Text + "<br />";
    Label1.Text += "TextBox1.Forecolor = " TextBox1.ForeColor.ToString();
    if(IsClick)
    {
    TextBox1.Text = "Some more text";
    TextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  IsClick=true;
}
```

This is My Idea

Comment: He wants the label to change to reflect the change to the textbox. This will force him to have to reload the page to get an updated label, which is what is unexpected and he thinks should not happen.